# Keras or TensorFlow, which one should I Choose for CNN project?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, project, conv-neural-network

I'm a beginner in machine learning, I don't know which library I have to choose for my internship project (Keras or TensorFlow), can you help me please.

Comment: Keras will be easier for you as TensorFlow constantly updates their versions. So you may encounter lot of bugs. Keras is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose Keras, make sure you choose `Keras` inside `TensorFlow`, **not the** `keras` **standalone package**.

So practically you would choose TensorFlow(with Keras inside). The `keras` inside TensorFlow is updated accordingly and works better(for the future) as compared to the standalone `keras` library.

Answer (score 0):

Keras is built on top of Tensorflow and is much easier to interact with (it can work with other backends as well). **Keras** is definitely the way to go for you.

(Personally I prefer PyTorch but you asked about Keras vs. TF)

Comment: Can you please tell me what are the benefits of PyTorch? I didn't find a lot of tutorials with it, for that reason I didn't put it in my choice list.

Comment: The dynamic computation graph is the main reason. It enables things that are sometimes  very cumbersome as opposed to TF. Pytorch is also way simpler than TF (when I started I didn't know about Keras). Nowadays Fast.ai gives an even better simplification and allows one to get going with DL and get great results on standard tasks in no time. You can see their course to get going

Comment: I find Keras simpler to use than PyTorch and I haven't run into any issues where I really needed the low level control that PyTorch offers. I have tried to work with straight TensorFlow but found it very convoluted (no pun intended ;-)

Comment: I agree about TF, and Keras is indeed convenient. The nice thing about pytorch is that it's actually usable for normal people while still giving you access to low level operations if you need something like that. OpenAI recently announced that they are moving entirely to PyTorch; they know a thing or two about DL :)